# Testing the quality simple linear regression model

Tags: regression

I have made a simple linear regression model based on two sets of monthly data from 1960 to 2008, using only data from 1960 to 2000.

I was now wondering how I would go about back-testing this model so I can comment on its quality.

So far I have predicted the values of the dependent variable using the independent variable from 2000 to 2008 and made a residual plot.  What else can I do to test the quality of my regression model?